# How to proper iterate through object and display it on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to write a simple quiz that will list all the data that is stored in `questionObj`. At first I would like to display in a container `quiz-container` the question along with possible answers.

Unfortunately, the loop duplicates the answers from previous questions. I have no idea how I can get rid of this error. Below is the code I wrote along with a jsFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var questionObj = {
    'JS': [{
        "question": "1. What is?",
        "correctAnswer": 2,
        'options': {
          "a": "Answer A",
          "b": "Answer B",
          "c": "Answer C",
          "d": "Answer D"
        }
      },
      {
        "question": "2. What is?",
        "correctAnswer": 2,
        'options': {
          "a": "2Answer A",
          "b": "2Answer B",
          "c": "2Answer C"
        }
      },
      {
        "question": "3. What is?",
        "correctAnswer": 2,
        'options': {
          "a": "3Answer A",
          "b": "3Answer B",
          "c": "3Answer C"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  $('body').append('<h1 class="page-header"></h1>');
  $('.page-header').html("Quiz!");
  var answers = [];
  questionObj.JS.forEach(function(question, questionNumber) {
    $('body').append('<div class="quiz-container">' + question.question + '</div>')
    for (var letter in question.options) {
      $('.quiz-container').append('<li>' + question.options[letter] + '</li>')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.page-header {
  font-size: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
  color: white;
}

.quiz-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/843gt5rg/

Comment: probably because you use a class to append your `li`. Every element created with the class will have it appended. Note: this is not JSON data, it's just a JS object

Comment: @Kaddath What do you think JSON stands for?

Comment: @LarsPeterson for a Notation, which is by nature a way to write text. JSON comes in a string. When decoded, it is not JSON anymore. Or maybe do you believe JSON decoded in PHP to be a JS object too?

Comment: @Kaddath Notation means text that represents something. When writing JSON, you are defining the keys and values of a JS object.

The OP used JSON to define the object. Otherwise, he would have used `obj.question = 'something'`.

I don't understand why decoding JS objects in PHP is relevant to our argument.

Comment: @LarsPeterson it would be true if the syntax to write an object in JS would be the same as in JSON, which is not the case. The simple fact that there are single quotes for keys in his code invalidates it for JSON, which is a communication notation standard. They are not interchangeable (edit: not that i specially want to argue about that)

Comment: @Kaddath I believe that was a user error. Otherwise, why would he use proper JSON markup for everything else?

But if not, touche.

Comment: @LarsPeterson yeah i'm splitting hair in 4 here (french expression, means i am being picky).. i usually add this as note because i often seen this as a source of errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you append the answers to the div by class, yet all three question containers have the same class, so the answers are duplicated per question.

To fix this you should create the question container and retain a reference to it in a variable. You can then `append()` to that element *only* within the loop through the answers, like this:

```
questionObj.JS.forEach(function(question, questionNumber) {
  var $question = $('<div class="quiz-container">' + question.question + '</div>').appendTo('body');
  for (var letter in question.options) {
    $question.append('<li>' + question.options[letter] + '</li>')
  }
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var questionObj = {
    'JS': [{
      "question": "1. What is?",
      "correctAnswer": 2,
      'options': {
        "a": "Answer A",
        "b": "Answer B",
        "c": "Answer C",
        "d": "Answer D"
      }
    },{
      "question": "2. What is?",
      "correctAnswer": 2,
      'options': {
        "a": "2Answer A",
        "b": "2Answer B",
        "c": "2Answer C"
      }
    },{
      "question": "3. What is?",
      "correctAnswer": 2,
      'options': {
        "a": "3Answer A",
        "b": "3Answer B",
        "c": "3Answer C"
      }
    }]
  }

  $('body').append('<h1 class="page-header"></h1>');
  $('.page-header').html("Quiz!");

  var answers = [];
  questionObj.JS.forEach(function(question, questionNumber) {
    var $question = $('<div class="quiz-container">' + question.question + '</div>').appendTo('body');
    for (var letter in question.options) {
      $question.append('<li>' + question.options[letter] + '</li>')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.page-header {
  font-size: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
  color: white;
}

.quiz-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I meant. In the future I will have this in mind

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You were appending html to a selector of **class** which is same for all question, I have included an **id** attribute which is different for all question div and use that **id** selector to append html:

```
 questionObj.JS.forEach(function(question, questionNumber) {
    $('body').append('<div class="quiz-container" id="question_'+questionNumber+'">'+question.question+'</div>')
    for(var letter in question.options) {
      $('#question_'+questionNumber).append('<li>'+question.options[letter]+'</li>')
    }

  })
```

I have edited you jsfiddle: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/843gt5rg/1/)